# A question about database design

Tags: database-design

I am planing on a Library Management System where students check out items.

My problem is with how to design the database if the library carry different medias (eg. mircofilm, dvds, cds etc) along with books.  My problem lies with the fact that dvds don't have the same attributes that of books, or books don't have the same attributes as microfilms.

So, how should I handle all these different types of medias?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the various media have some common attributes then put those in one table and put the other attributes in a separate table each.

Further, this common table should have a mediaType field, which is a foreign key from another table.

For example

**Table MediaType**

```
Id  Name
1   Book
2   DVD
3   CD
4   Microfilm
```

**Table Media**

```
Id  MediaType  Title
1   1          Gone With the Wind
2   2          Avatar
3   2          Gladiator
4   2          Never Say Never
5   3          Some Music CD
```

**Table MediaBook**

```
Id MediaId  Author
1  1        Margaret Mitchell
```

**Table MediaDVD**

```
Id  MediaId  Director
1   2        James Cameron
```

etc.

This way design will also help in any reporting you need to do since your Media table can point to the table in which additional information for the specific type of media exists. This design will also allow you to extend the attributes of various media independently of other types of media as well as easily add new media types to your system. This design will also give you a normalized data model while maintaing the integrity of your data using simple relationships and null/not null fields.

Comment: This sounds good.  I should have thought about this by myself but I must have been over thinking it.  Thanks Shiv.

Answer (score 2):

Would an option not to have a MediaType reference table, holding the types of media you have, and then the main transaction table has ALL possible fields... Then, have check constraints based on the MediaTypeId, checking which fields can and can't be NULL?

I find that the simplest and most maintainable solution.

Comment: Thanks buddy.  It does look pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to use enhanced ER model, in order to put the common items in a generic entity and the specailiced attributes in separate tables:

http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cse670/cse670Ch16.xht

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [free data model](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/media_libraries/index.htm) about Media libraries, from the  [Database Answers Website](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/).

Comment: I saw this but got stump by the icons used.  I will be able to learn more since I am looking at the symbols used.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simple option is to have a table for each media type.

Does this even count as an answer? :)

Comment: LOL.  Just over thinking it I guess.